# echo printing working directory files names for no reason

Tags: linux, shell, grep, echo

why echo printing the files names ?

```
sinks_index=`pacmd list-sinks | grep "index:"`

for i in $sinks_index
    do  
        echo $i
    done
```

gives this output

```
audio_name_switcher.sh
audio.py
audio.sh
switch_audio.sh
index:
1
index:
2
index:
3
```

but running `pacmd list-sinks | grep "index:"`  in the shell gives  `* index: 1 index: 2 index: 3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pacmd` returns `*` pattern.

In `for ... in ...; do ... done` loop, the list pattern contains `*` without any protection.

So, bash replace `*` by all files found in current directory.

It's the *glob* functionality.

You could temporary deactivate *glob* with `GLOBIGNORE` variable (see `man bash`):

```bash
#! /bin/bash
sinks_index='* index: 1 index: 2 index: 3'

GLOBIGNORE="*"
echo "With GLOBIGNORE"
for i in $sinks_index
    do
        echo "UNSET GLOB: " $i
        unset GLOBIGNORE
        echo "  SET GLOB: " $i
        echo "  SET GLOB: $i"
    done
unset GLOBIGNORE
```

Reactivate global **in** and **after** loop.

- In: it may be necessary for other stuff;
- After: if your list is empty, the execution do not enter in the loop.

Note about `$i` and `"$i"` after reactivate glob in the loop:

- The protection with `"..."` stop glob for bash echo command but do not stop `${...}` interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using an array for `sinks_index`, not a scalar:

```
sinks_index=( $(pacmd list-sinks | grep "index:") )

for i in "${sinks_index[@]}"
    do  
        echo "$i"
    done
```

The above will solve the problem you asked about but is making several assumptions about the output of `pacmd list-sinks` so consider that a starting point but you may need a more robust or slightly different solution depending on that output and what you actually want to do with it.

Copy/paste your shell scripts into http://shellcheck.net til you get familiar with shell.